# Semantic-UI Modal

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, semantic-ui

Просьба подсказать, как правильно работать с модальными окнами `Semantic UI`
имею следующий код:

```
$('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'i', function () {
            var data = empDataTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
            console.log(data['id']);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/show_by_id',
                type: 'post',
                data: {id: data['id']},
                success: function(data){
                    // $('.modal-body').html(data);
                    $('.modal-body').append(data.htmlresponse);
                    $('#alaris_id').modal({
                        transition: 'vertical flip',
                        blurring: true
                    }).modal('show');
                }
            });
        } );


<div class="ui modal" id="id">
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
</div>
```

Модальное окно вызывается по нажатию на элемент `i` в таблице, на данный момент это работает, но, при вызове следующего окна из таблицы, модальное окно отображает контент предыдущего запроса и текущего последующий вызов отображает также предыдущие элементы,
Просьба, подсказать, как корректно реализовать чтобы модальное окно показывала результат текущего запроса а не все которые были вызваны ранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас есть закомментированная строка с правильным решением. `.append()` добавляет результат в конец, а если там уже что-то есть, то к предыдущему добавится следующее. `.html()` заменяет содержимое элемента представленным кодом.

Поэтому вместо:

```
$('.modal-body').append(data.htmlresponse);
```

напишите:

```
$('.modal-body').html(data.htmlresponse);
```

и тогда всё будет заменяться как надо.

Comment: Благодарю, так работает, можете еще подсказать, как выстроить корректно, чтобы избавится от задержки при открытие, т.е. время запроса-ответ сервера, мгновенное открытие и в перспективе выставлю лоадер в модальное окно на время задержки

Comment: Никак, Вы же подгружаете данные, на это время нужно. Поэтому да, `spinner` во время загрузки, а после подменять.